# SELECT WHERE clause not working in Postgres (psql) when searching in a varchar column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `species_info` in Postgres SQL that is defined like this:

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| spccode | integer |  | not null |  |
| itis_tsn | character varying(10) |  |  |  |
| common_name | character varying(50) |  |  |  |
| scientific_name | character varying(100) |  |  |  |
| taxon_rank | character varying(25) |  |  |  |

And has values like this:

| spccode | itis_tsn | common_name | scientific_name | taxon_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Unidentified | None | None |
| 2 |  | Disintegrated fish larvae | None | None |
| 3 | 161109 | Tenpounders | Elopidae | Family |
| 4 | 161112 | Machete | Elops affinis | Species |
| 5 | 161119 | Bonefishes | Albulidae | Family |
| 7 | 161120 |  | Albula | Genus |
| 9 | 161694 |  | Clupeiformes | Order |
| 12 | 161743 | Round herring | Etrumeus teres | Species |

I do the following in psql:

```
select * 
from new_species_codes 
where common_name = 'Bonefishes';
```

and it works fine, returning the row with that value.

But when I try:

```
select * 
from new_species_codes 
where common_name = 'Machete';
```

it returns zero rows.

I've tried it with multiple values, and some of them work while others don't. What gives?

Comment: There might be a chance of `common_name` containing space

Comment: May be space or special character that you cannot see is present there..
you can check trim(common_name) = 'Herrings'
or common_name like '%Herr%' ..
based on it you can trace further.

Comment: Unless there is a row or rows with the exact value `'Herrings'` then you will get zero rows.  That would include values that have empty spaces, for example 'Herrings   '. Do you want an exact search or inexact(wildcard) search?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, there is a row with exact value 'Herrings', I just failed to include it in my snippet above.  I've also tried 'Machete' (edited the question to show this), and it didn't work.

Comment: @JayKumarR, yours seems to be the right answer.  I tried trim(common_name) and it works.

Comment: Then use the `trim()` suggestions from others as I'm guessing there are empty spaces in the values. The way to find out is;`select common_name, length(common_name) from new_species_codes where common_name ilike  'Machete%';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM new_species_codes 
WHERE TRIM(common_name) = 'Machete';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straightforward query and I tried as well, It is working as expected. Can you please confirm there is no blank space in between the common name start or trail?

[image]

Also, I would like to suggest using the LIKE operator when you searching for something using wildcard `where common_name like %Machete%`

[image]